# WCF: How do i return a .NET Framework class via Datacontract?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

As a beginner to WCF i want to implement a call to the Active Directory Service which gets all Users, the method looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    SearchResultCollection GetAllUsers();
```

SearchResultCollection is not serializable so i have to make something like this:

[DataContract]
SearchResultCollection

So i have to make my own wrapper class which inherits the *SearchResultCollection* or use *IDataContractSerializer*. Both solutions seems not easy.

The question: **How is the "standard" approach to use .NET Classes as a return type in a WCF service?**

(Writing a own DataContract for my own class seems easy. ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is create your own simple POCO class to represent `SearchResult`, and return a list of these objects. Really you want to be able to control exactly the information you need to send back from the service. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class MySearchResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And simply iterate the searech results and pull out the properties you need like so:

```
var results = new List<MySearchResult>();

foreach (SearchResult r in searchResultCollection)
{
    results.Add(new MySearchResult
                    {
                        Name = searchResult.Properties["Name"],
                        Email = searchResult.Properties["Email"]
                    });
}
```

That way the xml being sent back isn't bloated with all the properties you don't need AND you can serialize your own `List<MySearchResult>` return results. And by the way I have no idea if the Name and Email properties exist I am just showing an example.

Comment: Thank you :), so i have to do it myself. I hoped that the almighty .NET Framework would do it somehow automagicly. Or that there is already an automated approach for this kind of work.

Comment: No - there's no getting around the serialization issue, but aside from that even if you could mark it as a DataContract somehow you wouldn't want to just do a blanket return on all information in the object due to the message bloat.

Answer (score 3):

The `DataContract` route will suffice here.  The standard way is to decorate your class with the relevant attributes and it will be consumable by WCF in methods:

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class CustomerResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CustomerReference { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfMessagingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    CustomerResponse GetCustomer();
}
```

If the class is not serializable, I don't think even wrapping it will work.

However, the `SearchResultCollection` is itself returned from a WCF method, so you could just pass that straight through your own service, or at the very least, wrap it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just return a List of User where User is a custom User class flagged as Serializable. The method that gets the data from active directory can populate the User class by looping through the result.